# Merge two curves with geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

I have this simple geometry nodes setup
[image: gm]

which gives me the following result

[image: preview_1]

As you can see, the junction between the two curves is not merged properly, so when it is converted to mesh it does not look like a contiguous line

[image: preview_2]

Is there a way to properly merge the two curves?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use curve to mesh -> merge by distance -> mesh to curve after your "join geometry" node

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!

Comment: Short and sweet :)